# Errors in compiling Android 4.4.4 system applications

Tags: android

I want To translate system application on my cell phone. )Android 4.4.4(
But when I try to compile back after the changes have an error message:
It's call blocking application

> warning: string 'default_feature_bar_new' has no default translation.
> /data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/AndroidManifest.xml:16: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uuiTheme' in package 'android'

& It's contacts

> warning: string 'default_feature_bar_new' has no default translation.
> warning: string 'fast_dial_settings' has no default translation.
> warning: string 'fast_dialer' has no default translation.
> /data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/res/layout/contact_editor_accounts_changed_activity_with_picker_overlay.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@*android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Dialog').

```
/data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/res/layout/contact_editor_accounts_changed_activity_with_text_overlay.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@*android:style/Holo.Light.Dialog.ButtonBar').

/data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/res/layout/contact_editor_accounts_changed_activity_with_text_overlay.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@*android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Dialog').

/data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/res/layout/contact_editor_accounts_changed_activity_with_text_overlay.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@*android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Dialog').
```

These errors appear without any editing.
What is possible to do?
Information
Apktool Version (apk editor pro)
Operating System (android)
APK From? (ROM) -
Questions to ask before submission
Have you tried apktool d, apktool b without changing anything? YES
If you are trying to install a modified apk, did you resign it? YES

Comment: "data/data/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro/files/decoded/AndroidManifest.xml:16" If you are using Apk Builder by heago, lemme tell you it's an outdated IDE and doesn't work most of the times.

Comment: What software is recommended to use?